# HTML - Can't open a file from a parent(?) folder

Tags: html, css

This is my file structure:

```
/www/
 ∟--/first-web.site/
    ∟--index1.html
    ∟--/css/
       ∟--style.css
 ∟--/second-web.site/
    ∟--index2.html
```

I want to use style.css from 1-st website in my 2-nd website's index2.html. I tried `link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../first-web.site/css/style.css">`, but it doesn't work and F12 says that request was made for `https://second-web.site/first-web.site/css/style.css`. Absolute link works, but I'm not sure should I use it or not.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: give absolute link and if both sites use same css the good idea is to take out the css folder and not just keep it inside first's folder only.

Comment: I'm on Nginx & Ubuntu, if it does matter. Also, second website used as a subdomain for the first one, but they're in the different folders in /www/ for some reason

Comment: @WahabShah where should I place my css folder then?

Comment: Alright..Well sub domains will have different folder. So lets say you have some shared css and some specific css. So the shared css can be put at the level of first-web and second-web. Like may be shared_media folder and shared_media can have your css folder, images folder etc.But respective css can stay inside respective folders.

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it would be the full absolute path that you would need to use - the 'www' folder of a web server is what we call a 'virtual' folder. It has no physical location on the server but is more a directory of locations of the actual physical location of the files/folder that make up the site. Therefore none of these folders are relative to each other they each exist independently, even if they're in the same physical root folder.

Hope that helps clear it up a bit.

Comment: There's no /css/ folder in my active folder to use `css/style`, it's in other website directory

Comment: Ahhh yeah my bad sorry in that yeah it would be the full absolute path - I'll get that edited now and explain why

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 0):

The client doesn't know the internal file structure of your web server, so using absolute addresses (`http://first-web.site/css/style.css`) would be the correct approach here.

Comment: And no other way like file:/// or symlink?

Comment: @VioletLilium You could create a symlink from second-web.site/css to first-web.site/css on the server machine, but I doubt that's the best approach.

Comment: It works now, thanks. Why do you think it's not a good solution?

Comment: Well, it does its job of deduplicating the data, but you might eventually forget about the symlink in the future and uknowingly create a copy of the data. Absolute addresses are more explicit and you right away notice any issues.